# Use Makefile to Load Specific CSS Styles

Tags: css, shell, command-line, makefile

I am working with some code at the moment that uses Makefile to load specific stylesheets. The makefile is in the same directory as the dependency CSS files but when I reload the page that relies on makefile working, the styles are not being applied?

This is the makefile:

```
all: style-combined.css featured-my-combined.css featured-my-separate.css
    echo "all"
style-combined.css: style.css style-mob.css 
    cat style.css style-mob.css > style-combined.css
 featured-my-combined.css: featured.css featured-my.css featured-my-mobile.css
    cat featured.css featured-my.css featured-my-mobile.css > featured-my-combined.css
featured-my-separate.css: featured.css featured-my.css
    cat featured.css featured-my.css > featured-my-separate.css
```

The dependency CSS file are definitely there so is there something else that needs to be done for the makefile to work?  Or is there mistakes?

I've not used makefile before and still trying to get my head around this so any help is much appreciated.

**Update:**

I did some further research and found that the makefile is syntactically correct.  All I had to do was navigate to the CSS directory in the command line and run the make command which used the necessary dependencies to build the appropriate target CSS file.  Hopefully this will be useful to someone out there.

Thanks